# eval method in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

if you have something like this

```
var x='y';
var z='x';
```

if we want to get value of x (i.e y )from z we can achieve like this

eval(z) which will give you 'y'.

My question is if i am having x as an array like

```
var x=[a,b,c];
var z='x';
```

how can i get the x array values like `x[0],x[1],x[2]` using variable z.

we can't use like `eval(z[0])`,if we gave like `eval[z]` we will get like `[a,b,c]` but i want to access individual array elements directly.what is the way to achieve this.

Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `x` is a global, you can use `window`:

```
window[z][0] === a; // true
```

...but only if `x` is a global, and it's frankly not a good idea in any case.

To do this with non-globals, put `x` on an object:

```
var obj = {x: [a, b, c]};
```

...and then use `obj`:

```
obj[z][0] === a; // true
```

In both cases, this works because you can access an object property in JavaScript using either "dot notation" and a literal property name (`foo.bar`), or "bracketed notation" and a string property name (`foo["bar"]`). In the second case, you can have any expression for the string.

The reason `window` works for global variables is that in JavaScript, all global variables are properties of the global object, and on browsers you can reference that global object using the symbol `window`. (In fact, `window` itself is a property of the global object, that the object uses to refer to itself.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use window

```
window[z][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `eval(z)[0]`.
You have an array just after you do the eval step, not before. So `z[0]` is not really defined.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing via indexes can happen only after `eval`.

Try:

```
var x=['a','b','c'];
var z='x';
eval(z)[0];//this will give a
```